# Is it ok for Chili pepper plant's fruits to fall into its soil?

Tags: botany

I wonder if Chili pepper's fruits which fall into the soil near the plant will harm it, since the peppers are so spicy for people.

Comment: The spiciness is because human tongues can interact with Capsaicin - an organic molecule that locks into receptors on our papillae and cause a heat/pain feeling. Not all animals have them, and I doubt the soil would be affected since the seeds - where the highest concentration exists - must be planted. However, I can't look up references right now. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @MCM says, the capsaicin molecule isn't intrinsically damaging - its effect upon us is mediated through [the TRPV1 (Transient Receptor Potential Vanilloid 1) receptor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRPV) in the membranes of cells whose function is to sense noxious stimuli such as heat. The binding of capsaicin to this protein causes transmembrane movement of Ca<sup>2+</sup> ions which depolarises the membrane, triggering an action potential - a signal to the brain. Heat has the same effect on the TRPV1 protein. In this way the presence of capsaicin mimics the effects of heat, causing a painful sensation.

Have a look at [this SE.Biology question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/371/how-is-temperature-sensed).